# I want to combine 2 jquery codes into one in order to resize some font sizes on small devices

Tags: jquery

I want to resize the fontsize of some span tags,but only on small devices, I have this 2 codes that I´ve used individually and haved worked so far. Unfortunatley I haven't been successful at combine them, any help will be apreciated. Thanks in advance. (by the way, I dont use media queries because that way  I'll resize the font size af all the span tags)

Theese are the 2 jquery codes and the html:

```js
if( $("span").css('font-size') == '96px') { 
    
    $("span").css('font-size','26px');

}

$(window).on('resize', function() {
    if($(window).height() > 400) {
  
    }else{

    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span style="font-size:96px;">test</span>
```

Comment: Putting your if statement inside the resize event would be beneficial.

Comment: I know Adriani6 , I've tried that but, it doesn't work. Obviously i'm doing something wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `$(window).height()` instead of `$(window).width()`,

try this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span style="color:red;font-size:96px;color:red;">test</span><br/>
<span style="line-height: 96px;font-size:72px;">test</span>

$(function(){
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        if($(window).width() > 400){            
            $('span').each(function(k,v){
                if($(v).css('font-size') === '26px'){
                    $(v).css('font-size','96px');                   
                }
            });   
        }else{
            $('span').each(function(k,v){

                if($(v).css('font-size') === '96px'){
                    $(v).css('font-size','26px');                   
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

demo : https://jsfiddle.net/cqy10n0n/6/

Comment: I spoke too soon man jeje, I´m sorry , but I'm looking for a code that detects first if an span tag have the value 'font-size','96px' and then, change the sizes of only those span tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) for this.

```css
span {
  font-size: 26px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
  span {
    font-size: 96px;
  }
}
```

```html
<span>test</span>
```

Comment: Thanks Bram, but I want to resize the font size only of the span tags that have the value "font-size:96px"
If I use media queries I'll resize the font size af all the span tags.

Comment: Good case to use classes for these spans then.